# $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] Not Returning Hindi Characters

Tags: php

I've been trying to get the server URL using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].
But it's not properly working with Hindi words.
e.g if URL contains the word **हेल्लो**, the output is: **%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%8B**
Here's the code I'm using so far:

```
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$path = htmlspecialchars( $path, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains the URL encoded version of the URL.
If you want to get the raw content, pass it to `urldecode()`.

Example:

```php
$encoded = '%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%8B';
$decoded = urldecode('%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%8B');

var_dump($encoded, $decoded);
```

Outputs:

```
string(54) "%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%8B"
string(18) "हेल्लो"
```